# How to interpret RSolve solution with negative factorial?

Tags: difference-equations

I'm having trouble interpreting the following result of `RSolve` to this difference equation:

```
RSolve[n1 F[n1+1, n2] == (n1+n2) F[n1, n2] + F[n1-1, n2+1] - F[n1, n2+1], 
  F[n1, n2], n1]
```

> [image]

The result makes no sense to me, since it is expressed as a sum over `K[1]` starting at `K[1] = 0` causing the factorial `(-1 + K[1])!` to diverge.

Is there some special interpretation of this factorial?

Comment: Note that the "solution" includes the function `F` on the right-hand-side, so it's not really a solution. In any case, your recurrence relation does not really define `F` for all `n1,n2`, so it cannot really be solved. Not sure how to interpret the output by MMA though.